# Can AEM live copies have different domain in MSM?

Tags: aem

In AEM, say for example we have live copies for US and Russia and French countries in MSM and they all want to have different domain for every live copies

for example,

```
For US - www.abc.com/en.html
For Russia - www.def.com/rus.html
For French - www.ghi.com/fr.html
```

We may need to create separate vhost and dispatcher and sling mapping settings to achieve above but just want to know whether it is recommended in MSM and want to hear what are the issue would come if we have different domain for each live copies. Please share your experience if you have faced before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common occurrence. Have done this with live copies before and works just fine. Getting the sling maps right can be tricky for the uninitiated but nothing extraordinary. You need not have to have the country prefix in the path if the domains are unique, not sure of the intent behind having them in your case.